# android ArrayList to clean text to share by email

Tags: android, arraylist, format, tostring

I'm using the code below to retrieve two parameters from my `SQLite` db rows, `TITLE` and `NOTE`. I'm listing all inside `allnotes` `ArrayList`.
What I'm trying to do now is to share the `ArrayList` through email in a clean format.

```
DatabaseConnector dbConnector = new DatabaseConnector(MainActivity.this);
        dbConnector.open();
        c = dbConnector.ListAllNotesFull();
        while(c.moveToNext()) {
            Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<String, String>(2);
            data.put(TITLE, c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(TITLE)));
            data.put(NOTE, c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(NOTE)));
            allnotes.add(data);
        }
        dbConnector.close();

        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yy");
        String formattedDate = df.format(c.getTime());

        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        i.setType("message/rfc822");
        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{""});
        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "My app: my workouts backup " + formattedDate);
        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, allnotes.toString());
        try {
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Send mail..."));
        } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "There are no email clients installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

But the result I got in the email body is:

```
[{note=blabla, title=test}, {note=gdgfg, title=test2}]
```

should I use an Array instead? how can I format it to a clean string anyway? thanks

---

**EDIT**: the format i'd like the list to be is a simple

### Title

Note

(space here)

### Title

Note

etc.
(bold not necessary)

Comment: Using Array wouldn't help you here. You need to manually format it the way you want it to be. Please update your post with your desired format.

Comment: Hey thanks for your time, edited now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to iterate through the hashmap and fetch Notes, Titles value and append it in a string.
Something like this might be of your interest:

```
String noteTitleList = "";
    for(Map<String, String> data: allnotes)
    {
        Iterator it = data.entrySet().iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) 
        {
            Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)it.next();
            noteTitleList+= pair.getKey()+": "+pair.getValue()+"\n";
        }
        noteTitleList+= "\n";
    }
```

After this for loop you will have list of the NoteTitle pairs in your desired format. You can call Intent after this.

EDIT: To accommodate your format, given below, I have modified my above code.

Title

Note

(space here)

Title

Note

Comment: thanks for your answer, what i'm getting with your code is (with the correct vertical spaces): `Title: note
 Note: blabla

Title: title
 Note: test

Title: note
 Note: gdgfg

Title: title
 Note: test2`

Comment: to list the title before the note was enough to invert the `data.put` inside my hashmap code, but I still get all those repetitions as shown on reply above

Comment: changing last line of your code into `noteTitleList+= pair.getValue()+"\n";` lists everything fine but I'm missing the space between pairs

Comment: Thanks for clarifying requirement. I have edited it again. This should help.

Comment: It solved it thanks! I just got rid of `pair.getKey()+": "+` since I didn't want the words "title" and "note" to appear before the respective content but is essentially the same. cheers